# How to right align a ASCII String in a memory field in 8051 Assembly

Tags: assembly, alignment, microcontroller, 8051

I am a beginner in the world of microcontrollers and I have a problem in programming the 8051 microcontroller in the assembly language
I have to copy a sentence given in the "code memory", so for example "ABC" which gives 0x041, 0x042, 0x043 and 0x000 to the "data memory" field.
I can do it, except that I have to copy it and align it to the right ( Example on the screen )
I have searched the internet for information and help but I have not found any topics on alignment in this language for this 8051 microcontroller.

[Right-Alignment in the data memory for the sentence "ABC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzTf5.jpg)

I hope that someone could help me because I am a little lost about this language.
Thank you for your time

So I am going to show you what I did first to copy the code memory into the data memory. [Left aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AhWN.jpg)

[Left-aligned in the data memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1ffu.jpg)

And I don't really know how to right-align the 41,42,43 on the same line. I don't think that we can use C, but just assembly language here.

Comment: Point a reg at the start of the code string, point a register at the end of the data buffer, (maybe less one to allow a terminating NUL), then load, check for NUL, store if not, increment source pointer reg, decrement destination pointer reg, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Byte, character, and string manipulation is algorithmic, rather than language specific.  Can  you do it in C or pseudo code?  If not, then work on that first, then you'll know what you're trying to do when it comes to the assembly part.  Developing an algorithm from scratch by thinking only in assembly is very hard when learning assembly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Please [edit] your question and provide your attempt to solve this task. -- Where exactly are you stumbling? Can you copy left aligned?

Comment: Sorry I am going to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your right alignment picture well, you will see that from the memory address 0x40 to 0x4D, the cells are filled with value **20**. This value is **space character** value in *ASC2* table. Since we know that the each row in the memory table consists of 16 cells, we can use the same trick in the `DB` definition. This is not the best solution but will work. Just define your `DB` with leading 13 spaces like this and try it out:

```
DB "             ABC"
```